# Embedding videos from youtube in a generic way

Tags: html, css, youtube

I am creating a web site where users submit their (raw) youtube links and the system should automatically embed them. However, I cannot embed the youtube videos unless I get the special embed link given by youtube. How can I manage to embed any youtube link provided to the system ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cenmre, I have the perfect solution for you.

YouTube supports oEmbed, which lets you send it any URL, and get back the appropriate embed code.

Read more about [the standard](http://oembed.com/), and how [YouTube supports it](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just drop this in, and update video_id as need be?

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: but what if the user submits a link like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEQFsK3nORw&feature=relmfu to the system ? Is there a way to get the video's ID from any youtube link? I was thinking a way that will enable me to just update the src attribute.

Comment: Then you'll need to regex video_id out from the watch?v=... section when they submit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I may actually end up using this rather than the above solution since it is probably faster.